# Python: Beautifulsoup returns wrong decode for tis-620, charset windows-874

Tags: python, utf-8, beautifulsoup, decode, encode

I am trying to read Thai website with code tis-620 and convert the result to utf-8, so i could upload to any database.

I am noticed following behavior of beautifulsoup.

Simple example

### Source:

"""http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-874"

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-874" />
    <meta name="description" content="Discussion Forum" />
    </head>
    <body>
        hello
        <dl>
            <dt>no  English Thai    abbrev. phonemic</dt>
            <dt>01  January มกราคม  ม.ค.    mohkH gaL raaM khohmM</dt>
            <dt>02  February    กุมภาพันธ์  ก.พ.    goomM phaaM phanM</dt>
            <dt>03  March   มีนาคม  มี.ค.   meeM naaM khohmM</dt>
            <dt>04  April   เมษายน  เม.ย.   maehM saaR yohnM</dt>
            <dt>05  May พฤษภาคม พ.ค.    phreutH saL phaaM khohmM</dt>
            <dt>06  June    มิถุนายน    มิ.ย.   miH thooL naaM yohnM</dt>
            <dt>07  July    กรกฎาคม ก.ค.    gaL raH gaL daaM khohmM</dt>
            <dt>08  August  สิงหาคม ส.ค.    singR haaR khohmM</dt>
            <dt>09  September   กันยายน ก.ย.    ganM yaaM yohnM</dt>
            <dt>10  October ตุลาคม  ต.ค.    dtooL laaM khohmM</dt>
            <dt>11  November    พฤศจิกายน   พ.ย.    phreutH saL jiL gaaM yohnM</dt>
            <dt>12  December    ธันวาคม ธ.ค.    thanM waaM khohmM</dt>
        </dl>
   </body>
   </html>
```

---

Python pgm:

### 1. example

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date
import sys

sys.setdefaultencoding("tis-620")
reload(sys)
fthai = open('translation_thai.html','r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(fthai.read())
ln = soup.findAll('dl')
translation=[]
dttag = ln[0].findNext('dt')
for el in dttag.nextSiblingGenerator():
    if el <> u'\n':
        ss = el.get_text()
        vsep = el.get_text().encode('utf8').split('\t')
        line=[]
        for x in range(0,3):
            line.append(vsep[x])
        translation.append(line)
fthai.close()
```

---

ss returns u'03\tMarch\t\xc1\xd5\xb9....

vsep returns ['03','March','\xc3\x81\xc3......

what is wrong according to the utf8 table

### 2. example without beautifulsoup

```
import urllib2
import sys

sys.setdefaultencoding("tis-620")
reload(sys)
fthai = open('translation_thai.html','r')
array = []
x=-1
for line in fthai:
    x=x+1
    array.append( line )
    print array[x],x
sp = array[17].split('\t')
sp1 = sp[2].encode('utf8')
```

---

sp returns ['   03','March','\xc1\xd5\xb9......

sp1 returns '\xe0\xb8\xa1\xe0\xb8\xb5

correct!

according to utf8 table

3617    e21 ม E0B8A1  1110 0000 1011 1000 1010 0001   ม

3637    e35 ี E0B8B5  1110 0000 1011 1000 1011 0101   ี

Does anybody has a tip how I could fix the wrong behavior.

Comment: What happens if you run BS4 without `sys.setdefaultencoding()`?

Comment: it's the same as abovess returns u'03\tMarch\t\xc1\xd5\xb9....

vsep returns ['03','March','\xc3\x81\xc3......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**My solution:**

i call now convert instead of encode('utf-8'), it's a bit slow, but it worked.

```
def convert(content):
    #print content
    result = ''
    for char in content:
        asciichar = char.encode('ascii',errors="backslashreplace")[2:]
        if asciichar =='':
            utf8char = char.encode('utf8')
        else:  
            try:
                hexchar =  asciichar.decode('hex')
            except:
                #print asciichar
                utf8char = ' '
            try:
                utf8char = hexchar.encode('utf-8')
            except:
                #print hexchar
                utf8char = ' '
            #print utf8char

        result = result + utf8char    
        #print result
    return result
```